# What kind of encoding is this?

Tags: php, character-encoding

What kind of encoding is this: %26%23963;%26%23954;
and how can I encode letters from normal utf8 to this with php?

Thanks for your help!
phpheini

Comment: That's not encryption... That's encoding and it seems to be just regular url encoding.

Comment: My question should rather have been: How can I transform this: σκ beeing in the URL to unicode character entities like &#963;&#954;

Answer (score 3):

Looks like URL Encoding to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's URL-encoded:

```
echo urldecode('%26%23963;%26%23954'); // &#963;&#954;
```

which would appear to be two unicode character entities:

```
963 - small greek sigma
954 - small greek kappa
```

Comment: If that's how it's being passed in to you. But don't just blindly try url_decode on everything. Decoding something that wasn't encoded in the first place could "break" the string.

Comment: What I actually want to do is: if the URL contains russian or greek letters like "σκ", then these should be transformed in a way that can be searched in the database (that form would be: &#959;&#943;) So it is actually the other way round.

Comment: Why not just store the characters in their native encoding? MySQL supports all kinds of character encodings, then you wouldn't have to worry about double-encoding problems.

Comment: Yeah, but I allready have the database with contents with the type &#959;&#943;

Comment: `%CF%83%CE%BA` would have been a lot shorter.

Comment: well I guess thats too late. :(

Answer (score 0):

Off hand it looks like url encoded.
On this site http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ it comes out as σκ

```
&#963;&#954;
```

Comment: Yes. Its a url encoded string. How can I decrpt it from %26%23963;%26%23954; to σκ?

Comment: But I can not do something like urldecode($_GET["something"]); can I?

Comment: it depends on whether it was like www.yoursite.com/?something=%26%23963;%26%23954;

Comment: Yes, it was like that. But here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php it says, not to use it with $_GET!

Comment: @phpheini, you don't need it with `$_GET`, because PHP handles it for you.

Comment: so what do I give as string, that has to be decoded? In the php.net-example there is written: `$a = explode('&', $QUERY_STRING);
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($a)) {
    $b = split('=', $a[$i]);
    echo 'Value for parameter ', htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[0])),
         ' is ', htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[1])), "<br />\n";
    $i++;
}`

but I dont get it!

Answer (score 0):

First off, this isn't encryption... unless of course you consider ROT-13 encryption.

Looks to me that you are percent-encoding the decimal value of the UTF-8 characters.

Comment: actually this is what comes out in the URL when I have a form with greek or russian letters.

Comment: Right.... which is URL encoding.  Percent-encoding is a less way of saying URL encoding, as you didn't mention before you were using a URL.  What is your question?

Comment: if the URL contains russian or greek letters like "σκ", then these should be transformed in a way that can be searched in the database (that form would be: &#959;&#943;)
So how can I transform these greek letters?